# How to launch cmd with custom directory -- Windows 10

Tags: windows, command-line

I've recently installed python and found that cmd is convenient for running python scripts, but it is tedious changing the directory every time I open it.

Is there a way to set up a custom launch of command which opens pointed at my desired directory, while still keeping the default version of cmd as is, and could it be explained for a cmd user novice?

Answer (score 1):

Close enough, I hope.

Create a batch file (text file with the extension .BAT) such as DO.BAT and save it in C:\Windows or somewhere else in your path.

Contents of DO.BAT

```
cd \path
cmd
```

Then, execute it with {Win-R}DO{Enter}
or make a shortcut on your desktop to it, and execute by double-clicking it

You can name it anything which isn't already the name of an [internal](https://ss64.com/nt/) or external command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click your mouse on a blank spot on your desktop
2. Go to **New** and select **Shortcut**
3. In the new window that is brought up, in the field that says **Type the location of the item** enter the following:
   `cmd /K "cd C:\Program Files\Python37"`  (or wherever your python directory is)
4. Click **Next** and give your shortcut a name
5. Click **Finish** and you're done. The new shortcut that was created will open cmd prompt in your python directory